# menu_tree_output() not returning full menu array

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I'm building a function that takes a drupal rendered menu and removes the classes from it so that I can pass it to a jQuery function that'll build a menu from it.

The code i'm using for that is:-

```
<?php
     $tree = menu_tree_all_data("devel-frus");
     $menu = drupal_render(menu_tree_output($tree));
     $nocss = preg_replace('/class=".*?"/', '', $menu);
     echo($nocss);
?>
```

However `menu_tree_output()` seems to be only returning the first level of a six level menu when it should be returning the complete menu.

I've tried `dsm()`'ing `$tree` to see if all of the menu items are being returned by `menu_tree_all_data()` and that's fine, however when I `dsm()` the output of the `menu_tree_output()` function only the root and first level are returned in the array.

Am I doing something really obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand about [`menu_tree_all_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7.x) you need to supply it a link and depth to give it context (where in the menu tree am I at & how far do I go?). Also [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7.x) expects an argument passed by reference, so there will problems passing the output of function.

```
// Default to root link w/ a depth 5.
$link = menu_get_item();
$tree = menu_tree_all_data("devel-frus", $link, 5);
$tree_output = menu_tree_output($tree);

// Supply a variable for drupal_render to reference.
$menu = drupal_render($tree_output);

$nocss = preg_replace('/class=".*?"/', '', $menu);
echo($nocss);
```